# Passing an Implicit Parameter

Tags: scala, playframework

The code below gives an error *Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here* because *views.html.texts* expects an implicit request parameter to be in scope:

```
import play.api.mvc._

object MyController extends Controller {

  private def renderAction(result: Seq[String] => SimpleResult) = Action {
    implicit request =>
      val strs = Seq("a", "b", "c")
      result(strs)
  }

  def renderSomething = renderAction { strings =>
    views.html.texts(strings)
  }
}
```

How do I make this parameter available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` function should take `request` as parameter.

```
import play.api.mvc._

object MyController extends Controller {

  private def renderAction(result: Seq[String] => Request[AnyContent] => SimpleResult) = Action {
    implicit request =>
      val strs = Seq("a", "b", "c")
      result(strs)(request)
  }

  def renderSomething = renderAction { strings => implicit request =>
    views.html.texts(strings)
  }
}
```

Comment: @z12345 I never executed this piece of code, Please tell me if it didn't compile.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't find where *SimpleRequest* comes from.

Comment: My bad, I guessed the name. This should be the same type of `request` parameter, provided by `Action`, I think it is `Request[AnyContent]`